# uboot- MMC no SDcard

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot

I am trying to get a linux kernel with a linux rootfs running on an imx51 Freescale board.

I compiled linux kernel, root file system and u-boot and copied the image to SD-card: partition 0: boot partition 1: rootfs and linux kernel

However I have the following error:

```
U-Boot 2011.12 (Mar 13 2012 - 14:15:41)

CPU:   Freescale i.MX51 family rev3.0 at 800 MHz
Reset cause: POR
Board: MX51EVK
DRAM:  512 MiB
WARNING: Caches not enabled
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0, FSL_SDHC: 1
MMC: no card present
MMC init failed
Using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   FEC
Warning: failed to set MAC address

Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
MX51EVK U-Boot > mmcinfo
MMC: no card present
Device: FSL_SDHC
Manufacturer ID: 0
OEM: 0
Name: Tran Speed: 0
Rd Block Len: 0
MMC version 0.0
High Capacity: No
Capacity: 0 Bytes
Bus Width: 0-bit
MX51EVK U-Boot > mmc init
mmc - MMC sub system

Usage:
mmc read addr blk# cnt
mmc write addr blk# cnt
mmc erase blk# cnt
mmc rescan
mmc part - lists available partition on current mmc device
mmc dev [dev] [part] - show or set current mmc device [partition]
mmc list - lists available devices
MX51EVK U-Boot > mmc list
FSL_SDHC: 0
 FSL_SDHC: 1
MX51EVK U-Boot > mmc dev
MMC: no card present
mmc0(part 0) is current device
MX51EVK U-Boot >
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: My boot partition is 50 MB  and my rootfs partition is 3.64 GB of which 2.45 GB is used up with the kernel and RFS. I find that weird as I see that people talk about as small as 6MB file systems :(

Comment: Are you using the u-boot version that came with your evaluation board? Are you sure you ported the drivers correctly? It seems a driver problem to me because Manufacturer ID and MMC version is 0.

Comment: Oh. I got the latest uboot and compiled it for my Board by setting the configuration. Btw when I tried doing a git clone, it seems to fail.  git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot-imx.git
Cloning into u-boot-imx...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: cork
........Any ideas??

Comment: Ok just a question, should I have to always take the U-boot and Linux BSP with the kernel from the board manufacturer? as in this ase, freescale linux BSP with u-boot? I took the u-boot from denx website and compiled it for my board mx51evk and also took the latest kernel from the kernel.org and compiled it for ARM. Is this the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the DIP switches, I realized that the switch was set to boot the SDcard from the bottom slot while I had all along booted from top slot. Thus, it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

at file ./board/freescale/mx51evk/mx51evk.c

```
int board_mmc_init(bd_t *bis)
{                                                                  
    u32 index;                                                             
    s32 status = 0;                            
    esdhc_cfg[0].sdhc_clk = mxc_get_clock(MXC_ESDHC_CLK);                      
    esdhc_cfg[1].sdhc_clk = mxc_get_clock(MXC_ESDHC2_CLK);  
}
```

As per above code snippets, I would suggest to check clock source.
Try to probe clock on MMC0 source. There might be clock source issue.